# echo php variable in inline style

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, background-color

I've seen similar questions but nothing quite the same. In a DB, I have saved hex values for the background and border colors of a specific div. I've verified that I'm getting them out of the database. At the risk of sounding like an idiot: when trying to echo the variables in my inline style, it doesn't work:

```
<div style="background-color: <?php echo $bg ?>; border: 3px solid <?php echo $border ?>;" id="container">
```

I had the hunch that even though simply writing a hex code works fine, the string being produced by the variable can't register as a hex value. After some searching I tried a few of the following (without success):

```
function strToHex($string)
{
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
}
```

And

```
$bg=bin2hex($bg);
```

Anyway, am I missing something? Does the string being stored in my DB need to be converted somehow? How can I change the background color of this div, based on the hex code saved in my database?

Comment: what is the string that's stored in your db? give an example.

Comment: What does the resultant markup look like .... maybe you just need to add a # in front like `echo "#".$bg`

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  What *does* it do?  What is the rendered output?

Comment: Yur first line of code works in PHPFiddle. Check whatyou're getting from your database. Do your colour values have a leading `#`?

Comment: I can write <?php echo $bg; ?> and it produces the result: #519c2. When I write in the color #000000 where it says "<?php echo $bg ?>", it turns the div black, yet when using <?php echo $bg ?>, the background color is set to the default in the css file.

Comment: Mike, yes. In the DB, they start with #. I tried taking that out and adding it before echoing the varoable to no avail.

Comment: "doesn't work" = the background color does not change to the hex code that the php variable represents.

Comment: @developerwjk What do you mean what is the string? Like the actual value? The actual value being stored in the DB is #519c2. And I echoed it just before the div layer to make sure it was printing what I expect. It is.

Comment: I think we need to see the final markup. Take a look at the page source once your page is generated and post the relevant line here. It would probably also help to see how your DB is structured, and the query you're using to retrieve the data.

Comment: Here's a link to the page: http://54.213.116.19/backend/recorder/?tag=4331768332861376498309

Comment: And the DB query    $dbh=MYSQL_CONNECT(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR _log("saving.php: Can not connected to database.");
    @mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or _log("saving.php:  Can not select database.");
    
    $sql="select * from campaigns where tag='$tag' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $logo=$rows['logo'];
    $description=$rows['description'];
    $button=$rows['button'];
    $bg=$rows['bg-color'];
    $border=$rows['border-color'];
    $terms=$rows['terms'];
    $tag=$rows['tag'];
    $username=$rows['username'];

Comment: `#519c2` is not a valid color code. It should have either 3 hex digits or six. Is this a typo?

Comment: Hold on a sec. That may be the culprit haha

Comment: Thanks @MikeW. I feel like a dunce. My DB row is limited to 6 characters, but I included the pound symbol. I bet that's the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line from your page source:

```
<div style="background-color: ##00000; border: 3px solid #519c2;" id="container">
```

The two color codes are both incorrect. `##00000` should be `#000000`. `#519c2` is too short - it should have six hex digits.